# Fundamental primal polynomial associated to an integer

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

Under Goldbach's conjecture, let $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r>0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$ and $k_{0}(n):=\pi(n+r_{0}(n))-\pi(n-r_{0}(n))$ for any composite positive integer $n$. Let also $g_{1}(n),\cdots,g_{k_{0}}(n))$ be the $k_{0}(n)$ prime gaps appearing in the "fundamental primal interval" $[n-r_{0}(n),n+r_{0}(n)]$ and $\mathcal{P}_{0}(n)$ their product.

Denote by $\displaystyle{Q_{n}:X\mapsto\prod_{i=1}^{k_{0}(n)}(X-g_{i}(n))}$ the "fundamental primal polynomial associated to $n$" and denote by $a_{i}(n)$ its term of degree $k_{0}(n)-i$.

One has $a_{1}(n)=2r_{0}(n)$ and $a_{k_{0}(n)}=\mathcal{P}_{0}(n)$.
Also, $2^i\mid a_{i}(n)$.
Is there a way to recover the $g_{i}(n)$ from known results about prime gaps and the general theory of polynomials?
Also, which may be easier to answer, does $gcd(g_{1}/2,\cdots, g_{k_{0}(n)}/2)=1$ if $k_{0}(n)>1$?

Edit: I may have an idea to recover the $g_{i}$ from $k_{0}(n)$, $a_{1}(n)$ and $\mathcal{P}_{0}(n)$. First arrange those prime gaps in increasing order and write $g'_{i}=g_{\sigma(i)}$ with $i<j\Longrightarrow g'_{i}\leqslant g'_{j}$ for the relevant permutation $\sigma\in\frak{S}_{5}$ where I dropped $n$ to have lighter notations.

The idea is to approximate the $g'_{i}$ by consecutive terms $x_{i}$ of a geometric progression of first term $u_{0}$ and common ratio $q>1$, so that $x_{i}=u_{0}q^{i-1}$. One gets $a_{1}(n)=u_{0}\frac{1-q^{k_{0}(n)}}{1-q}$ and $u_{0}^{k_{0}(n)}q^{\frac{k_{0}(n)(k_{0}(n)-1)}{2}}=a_{k_{0}(n)}$, hence a set of two equations with two unknowns. Solving them gives $u_{0}$ and $q$, from which we deduce the $x_{i}$. Now we can set $x'_{i}$ as the even integer closest to $x_{i}$.

Does one then have $g'_{i}=x'_{i}$?

Comment: When you say recover the $g_i(n)$ you mean recover from what? From $Q_n$?

Comment: Essentially from the knowledge of $n$, $r_{0}(n)$ and $k_{0}(n)$.